# ubuntu 18.04->20.04; "unresolvable p*roblem ... unofficial software package"; launchpad PPA?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

sudo do-release-upgrade aborts with the message

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.
```

As a duffer I am looking for advice on how to proceed.

I need an argument for ppa-purge as in this from the help file

```
sudo ppa-purge [options] <ppa:ppaowner>[/ppaname]
```

How am I supposed to know which PPA is the culprit in order to purge it?

I think this helps

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade$ grep -E 'ERROR|failed' main.log
2023-09-27 11:44:22,459 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2023-09-27 11:44:22,525 INFO failed to remove python-dev
2023-09-27 11:44:22,555 INFO failed to remove libpython-dev
2023-09-27 11:44:22,586 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2023-09-27 11:44:22,616 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2023-09-27 11:44:22,645 INFO failed to remove python-dev
2023-09-27 11:44:22,645 INFO failed to remove libpython-dev
2023-09-27 11:44:22,645 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2023-09-27 11:44:23,172 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
tevs@tevs-SEi:/var/log/dist-upgrade$

However I don't know how to relate the items to PPAs. Is each line a separate PPA? 

If not, how do I relate these lines to a PPA?

If so, what is the PPA owner for these?
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running an `sudo apt update` command to uncover the faulty PPA information. The output will likely display a 404 error or something similar for faulty repositories.

To list all the PPAs in the Ubuntu repository, you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --list
```

Use the following command to remove a PPA from the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove <ppa:repository_name>
```

After that, update:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, retry the `do-release-upgrade` command, and repeat the procedure if it still fails.

Comment: Thanks. apt update did not show any problems.; sudo apt-add-repository --list only gives the help message for apt-add-repository; "apt list --installed | grep  -v bionic" shows chrome, drivers for my printer and one utility that I installed. All the packages work.; Are you suggesting that I should uninstall all of these in order to do the upgrade?

Comment: Probably. An alternate way would be to iterate over your /etc/apt directory (and comment out various lines n,ot related to the official linux repos. (in /etc/apt/sources.list file and/or /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* files)..Then re-update, and try your upgrade. May you show me the result of this command `grep -r *ppa* /etc/apt/`